# How to use repo as repository on Hudson

Tags: git, continuous-integration, hudson, repository

I work on a project using repo to control over a hundred git repositories and Hudson as continuous integration server. The file structure of the project is like:

```
./.repo
./a/.git
./b/.git
./b/c/.git 
./b/c/d/.git
... more than a hundred gits
```

The whole project must be built together, in other words, each git repository cannot be built separately. Is there any way to use Hudson work with repo which manages large number of git?

Comment: So the problem is building a deep dependency chain?  Could you describe the task in more detail, it will help to figure out what Hudson features may help.

Comment: The project is composed of hundreds of sub modules managed by a git repository respectively, and all the git repositories are controlled by a single repo. The source structure is similar to Android project source.( source.android.com/download/using-repo, for your reference)

Here’s the situation I have: I tried to create an upstream job in Hudson to execute repo command to get code from SCM, and then proceed with a downstream job using file system as SCM repository.  
However, a problem occurs when using some Hudson features such as SCM polling build.

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what "a problem occurs" means.   I think you need to rewrite the original question, but provide a lot more details.  Describe the jobs and how they are laid out.  Describe what problem you are running into.   Describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a "coordinator" top level project that is entirely composed of [Git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) pointing to the sub-projects might be a passable solution. Then, Hudson-invoked git commands, including cloning and committing and tagging could be done from the top project.

Comment: This is really how this project should have been created in the first place.  Submodules support nesting git repositories.  You should never nest git repositories using `repo`, and it is quite clear that the android project has gone out of their way to make sure it is that way.